# Using a case statement in a insert trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to modify a database trigger for insert. So if the StoreID equals 6005  then insert some text if not then insert the i.[BillEmail].

```
 INSERT INTO [FRTOOLS_Orders]
    (OrderNumber, ShipFirstName, ShipLastName, ShipCompany, ShipStreet1, ShipStreet2, ShipStreet3, ShipCity, ShipState, ShipPostalCode, ShipCountryCode, BillPhone, BillFax, BillEmail, RequestedShipping, OrderID, OrderTotal, EmailNotification)
SELECT i.[OrderNumber],
       i.[ShipFirstName] + ' ' + i.[ShipMiddleName],
       i.[ShipLastName],
       i.[ShipCompany],
       i.[ShipStreet1],
       i.[ShipStreet2],
       i.[ShipStreet3],
       i.[ShipCity],
       i.[ShipStateProvCode],
       i.[ShipPostalCode],
       i.[ShipCountryCode],
       i.[BillPhone],
       i.[BillFax], 
       CASE WHEN i.[StoreID] = 6005 THEN 'sales@***.com' ELSE i.[BillEmail],
       i.[RequestedShipping],
       i.[OrderID],
       i.[OrderTotal],
       i.[BillEmail]
FROM inserted i
```

Most likely this is not the correct way to use the CASE statement.
Sql error of 'Incorrect syntax near ',' '

Comment: You forgot the `END`: `CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment above you need to terminate a CASE statement with END

```
 INSERT INTO [FRTOOLS_Orders]
    (OrderNumber, ShipFirstName, ShipLastName, ShipCompany, ShipStreet1, ShipStreet2, ShipStreet3, ShipCity, ShipState, ShipPostalCode, ShipCountryCode, BillPhone, BillFax, BillEmail, RequestedShipping, OrderID, OrderTotal, EmailNotification)
SELECT i.[OrderNumber],
       i.[ShipFirstName] + ' ' + i.[ShipMiddleName],
       i.[ShipLastName],
       i.[ShipCompany],
       i.[ShipStreet1],
       i.[ShipStreet2],
       i.[ShipStreet3],
       i.[ShipCity],
       i.[ShipStateProvCode],
       i.[ShipPostalCode],
       i.[ShipCountryCode],
       i.[BillPhone],
       i.[BillFax], 
       CASE WHEN i.[StoreID] = 6005 THEN 'sales@***.com' ELSE i.[BillEmail] END,
       i.[RequestedShipping],
       i.[OrderID],
       i.[OrderTotal],
       i.[BillEmail]
FROM inserted i
```

Note that your case statement can have multiple WHEN Clauses (this may or may not be useful to you in this instance)

```
CASE 
WHEN i.[StoreID] = 0 THEN '<unknown>' 
WHEN i.[StoreID] = 6005 THEN 'sales@***.com' 
WHEN i.[StoreID] IN (9997,9999) THEN 'sales@blahblah.com' 
ELSE i.[BillEmail] END,
```